# HTML 5 File API - Upload File to Server via JQuery

Tags: json, model-view-controller, html, file-upload

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. I'm trying to let the user upload files to the server. I need to use the HTML 5 File API. Currently, I have the following code:

```
  <div><input id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="multiple" /></div>
  <div><input type="button" value="upload" onclick="return uploadFiles();" /></div>

    function uploadFiles() {
        var files = null;    // How do I get the files collection from "filesToUpload" here? 
        if ((files == null) || (files.length)) {
            alert("Please choose at least one file to upload.");
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
            uploadFile(reader.result);
        }
    }

    function uploadFile(f) {
        // TODO: I'm not sure how to finish my actual AJAX request to post the file back to the server.

        $.ajax({
            url: "/uploadFile",
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("File Uploaded!");
            },
            error: function (p1, p2, p3) {
                alert("Upload Failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see from the code, I have some knowledge gaps that I am trying to fill in.

1. How do I get the files collection from the "filesToUpload" HTML
   element via JQuery? The reason I want this approach is because I do
   not want to begin uploading until the user actually clicks the
   "upload" button I've shown below.
2. What do I set as the "data" value in my $.ajax attempt?
3. What should the contentType be in my $.ajax attempt?

Thank you very much for your help!